# Trouble with Flex Sensor and MCP3008

Tags: sensor, analog-to-digital, wiring

I'm working on a project currently, though things aren't quite working so I would like whoever's advice.

So, to put it briefly, I'm using a [Sparkfun Flex Sensor](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10264) and an MCP3008 hooked up via a Raspberry Pi. However, the MCP3008 is not picking up on the sensor's output. Well, that's what I think is happening at least. Anyways, I cannot seem to be able to figure out how to do this properly, and I'm not sure if this is a problem with the code or the wiring. In case you were wondering, I followed [Adafruit's tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/raspberry-pi-analog-to-digital-converters/mcp3008) and I am using their example code.

I've been experimenting with this for a day or two now. Sometimes, all channels seem to be getting a value of 1023, and other times it's just at 0.

As  of now I can't take a picture of it, but I'll make sure to upload one when I can.

Answer (score 1):

i couldn't comment as of now so answering anyway 
if copied the code right it should work fine

**Note**: Copy the code from GitHub not from the blog because in blog they present only snippets of code so check that out once again if it didn't work comment below

Comment: I did take the code from Github. It hasn't been working.

Comment: hope this video help you out [**link**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jDJAklvIuPY)if not your MCP is faulty

Comment: I tried that video you sent. It hasn't worked, for me at least. I'm trying to set up a voltage divider with the flex sensor. My MCP probably isn't faulty, I tested both of the MCPs I ordered and got the same output.

Comment: Pin 19 (MOSI ) -> pin 11 (Din)                                                               Pin 21 (MISO ) -> pin 12 (Dout)    Pin 23 (SCKL) -> pin 13 (CLK)
    Pin 24 (CD0 ) -> pin 10 (CS)
    Pin 6 (GND) -> pin 14 (AGND) & 9 (DGND)

Comment: try checking if any  VCC pin is connected to your channel pin in that case you get full value 1023

Comment: Now you are able to comment on other questions ;-)